# Why scala case class generates two apply methods?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to explore scala case class internals a bit. To do so I'm creating simple case classes and analyzing the bytecode that scala compiler creates using `javap`.

I'm quite surprised to find out that when I create a case class with only one String field:

```
case class MyCaseClass(value: String)
```

the bytecode of the companion object `MyCaseClass$` contains two `apply` methods:

```
  public MyCaseClass apply(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: new           #23                 // class MyCaseClass
       3: dup
       4: aload_1
       5: invokespecial #26                 // Method MyCaseClass."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: areturn

  public java.lang.Object apply(java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: checkcast     #53                 // class java/lang/String
       5: invokevirtual #55                 // Method apply:(Ljava/lang/String;)LMyCaseClass;
       8: areturn
```

(compiled using scalac 2.11.6)

The first one is the one I expected - taking String as an argument and creating a new instance of my case class passing this argument to the constructor. The second one takes an object, casts it to String and then calls the first one.

I cannot think of any uses of the second method. Why is it needed? Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default companion object extends a function type, in this case `Function1[String, MyCaseClass]` (normally written as `String => MyCaseClass` in Scala).

The JVM signature of `Function1#apply` is `Object apply(Object)` so the overriding method must have the same signature.

Comment: Thank you :) For anyone reading this in the future, I found out later that it is the way Java deals with generic types erasure - it's not Scala specific. Generated methods are called the "bridge methods" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html#bridgeMethods